# Modificar funcion de Policies

Tags: laravel, users-roles

Estoy intentando modificar la función de Policies que actualmente es esta:

```
public function pass(User $user, Product $product)
{
   return $user->id == $product->user_id;
}
```

A ver si me explico bien.. tengo unos productos que al intentar acceder a ellos comprueba que el `id` del **usuario** sea el mismo que el `user_id` del **producto** al que intenta acceder hasta aqui todo perfecto pero lo que tambien necesito es crear algunos productos que sean accesible a ellos por todos los usuarios sin restrinciones que todos los usuario sin importar su id tengan acceso a ellos. por ejemplo he pensado en usar el `user_id 1` en todos los productos sin restriccion pero no se plantearme como hacer que la funcion de acceso libre a todos los productos con `user_id 1` alguna idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que tu caso de uso es el siguiente:

Existen productos que pueden ser accedido por todos los usuarios y otro grupo de productos que tienen un acceso restringido en base al `user_id` del producto.

En base a esto propongo dos maneras.

### Modo 1

Que añadas un valor en la tabla producto que indique si el producto es restrictivo para el usuario indicado.

1 - Crear una migración y añadir `is_restricted`como booleano (o modificar la inicial):

```php
php artisan make:migration add_is_restricted_column_to_products_table --table=products
```

luego en `AddIsRestrictedColumnToProductsTable.php`:

```php
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('is_restricted')->default(true)->after('user_id');
        });
```

2 - Correr tu migración.

3 - Modificar tu policy:

```php
public function pass(User $user, Product $product)
{
    if ($product->is_restricted)
    {
        return $user->id == $product->user_id;
    }
    return true;
}
```

### Modo 2

Que establezcas el valor de `user_id` en la tabla producto a `null` en caso este producto sea accedido por todos. así, puedes comparar en tu policy:

```php
public function pass(User $user, Product $product)
{
    if ( ! is_null($product->user_id))
    {
        return $user->id == $product->user_id;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Puedes incluir un atributo en tu tabla producto que determine si ese producto es accesible por todos o solo por un cierto grupo de usuarios.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias